# Attempting to utilize text captured from a PDF

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array called `myArray` that contains words separated by a space and trimmed from a PDF from the first page to the last page. I wrote a simple `print` array method that iterates through and prints each element one by one and it looks great!

Immediately after I have it go through another `for loop` for the length of the array and checks `if (myArray[i].equals("(19)")) {//print something}` When printing the array to the console it is clear that the value `(19)` exists in the array.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessRead;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

public class Main {

    static File file;
    static PDFTextStripper textStripper;
    static PDDocument pdDoc;
    static COSDocument cosDoc;
    static String parsedText;
    static int sum = 0;
    static String[] myArray;
    static String[] events = {"400", "800", "1500",
            "3000", "5000", "10000"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Read the PDF file into instance variable file
        readFile();

        try {
            parsePDF(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        myArray = parsedText.split(" ");
        removeWhiteSpace(myArray);
        printArray(myArray);
        //System.out.println();

        String currentEvent = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

            if (contains(myArray[i])) {
                currentEvent = myArray[i];
            }

            if (!currentEvent.equals("")) {
                if (myArray[i].charAt(0) == '(' && (myArray[i].charAt(myArray[i].length() - 1) == ')')) {

                    String formatedRunners = "";

                    //It is possible to see some numbers such as (19)) or (19)
                    if (containsCharacter(myArray[i], ')') == 2) {
                        formatedRunners = myArray[i].substring(1, myArray[i].length() - 2);
                    } else {
                        formatedRunners = myArray[i].substring(1, myArray[i].length() - 1);
                    }

                    int numberOfRunners = Integer.parseInt(formatedRunners);
                    int distance = Integer.parseInt(currentEvent);


                    sum += numberOfRunners * distance;

                    //reset currentEvent
                    currentEvent = "";
                }
            }
        }
        //Print total distance in meters
        System.out.println(sum + " meters");

        //Convert meters to miles using the following equation: meters / 1609.344 
        System.out.println( Math.round((sum / 1609.344)) + " miles");
    }

    public static void readFile() {
        Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a file path: ");
        String filePath = c.nextLine();
        file = new File(filePath);
    }

    public static void parsePDF(File file) throws IOException {

        textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        pdDoc = PDDocument.load(file);

        //Parse PDF
        textStripper.setStartPage(1);
        //textStripper.setEndPage();
        //Parsed String
        parsedText = textStripper.getText(pdDoc);

    }

    public static boolean contains(String s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
            if (s.equals(events[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void printArray(String[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }

    }

    public static void removeWhiteSpace(String[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

            if (myArray[i].equals("")) {

                //Use some filler to avoid crashes when checking characters
                myArray[i] = "NULL";
            }

            //Trim off all extra whitespace
            myArray[i] = myArray[i].trim();
        }
    }

    public static int containsCharacter(String str, char c) {

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == c) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Here is what I want:

1. Parsing and trimming etc. **(OK)**
2. Iterating over `myArray` (in the main method) and detecting events **(OK)**
3. If an event occurred then the next value must be `(Any number)` like `(19)`
   **(NOK)**
4. The number from step 3. will be used to compute another number
5. Reset the current event to repeat the process over and
   over again.

It seems like that it is reading each event correctly but only picks up (19)) instead of (19).

Comment: Sorry but your post is confusing. Especially the 2nd part below the code. One can rap it "My program should iterate through a **heat sheet** for a track and **field meet** and add up the total meters **real wheat**...." ;-) but it doesn't help to track down the problem. What I understood so far: (1) You extract text from a PDF and put each trimmed word into an array (2) you iterate over the array and for certain numbers you want to do  execute some action. So where is your problem? (1) or (2)? Please create an executable example...

Comment: My problem is iterating over the array (2). I am iterating over the array looking for an event that exists inside my event array, simple enough. Once that happens the next element in the array I stumble across should be a number between opening and closing parenthesis, this will be used to compute another number and reset the current event to repeat the process over and over again. I will work on getting you a live example very shortly, sorry for the confusion its quite the question to ask.

Comment: Since I don't have your PDF can you post an example output of the array I can test with? E.g. String [] myArray = {"someValue", "800", "(19)", "someothervalue", "400","19"}; What is the value of myArray? `(19)` or  `(19))`?

Comment: This would be the PDF: http://www.leonetiming.com/2019/Outdoor/Bucknell/Results.pdf

Originally I was using a PDF where there was a distinct pattern from event to the number of participants in an event (running events only). This PDF is a little different however it is exactly the PDF this program needs to work for. myArray ends up getting each string split up by a space and from there I am trying to come up with a solution to read each event followed by the number of participants without counting the same one twice as the same event header continues onto the next page if it doesn't fit.

Comment: To answer your question about an example myArray. Lets assume myArray = {"Seeded", "3000", "random", 25, "(44)", "1500", "random", "(13)"}

After iterating through I would want to add to a int sum variable: (3000 * 44) + (1500 * 13) as that would be the total meters ran out of those 2 events combined. The real issue arises when some numbers have (19)) or (19) meaning the (19)) is a continuation of (19) on the second page if the list is too long. In this case, I wouldn't want to add it a second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in you code (No Exceptionhandling, everything static, small bugs etc.) but I will focus on the major issue. (I removed the code which I did not change)

```
public class Main {

static File file;
static PDFTextStripper textStripper;
static PDDocument pdDoc;
static COSDocument cosDoc;
static String parsedText;
static int sum = 0;
static String[] myArray = {"Seeded", "3000", "random", 25, "(44)", "1500", "random", "(13)"};
static String[] events = {"400", "800", "1500", "3000", "5000", "10000", "200.000"};

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Read the PDF file into instance variable file
    readFile();

    try {
        parsePDF(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    myArray = parsedText.split(" ");
    removeWhiteSpace(myArray);

    String currentEvent = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

        if (contains(myArray[i])) {
            currentEvent = myArray[i];
        }
        else if (!currentEvent.isEmpty()) {

            Integer value = extractNumber(myArray[i]);

            if (!myArray[i].isEmpty() && value!=null) {

                int distance = Integer.parseInt(currentEvent);
                sum += value.intValue() * distance;

                //reset currentEvent
                currentEvent = "";
            }
        }
    }
    //Print total distance in meters
    System.out.println(sum + " meters");

    //Convert meters to miles using the following equation: meters / 1609.344 
    System.out.println( Math.round((sum / 1609.344)) + " miles");
}

public static Integer extractNumber(String toCheck) {
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile("^.*?\\([^\\d]*(\\d+)[^\\d]*\\).*$");

    Matcher m = r.matcher(toCheck);
    if(m.find()) {
        return Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
    }
    return null;
}

public static void removeWhiteSpace(String[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        //Trim off all extra whitespace
        myArray[i] = myArray[i].trim();
    }
}
```

The result is

`151500 meters
94 miles`

Comment: In this scenario what would be wrong with everything being static? I will not be instantiating any objects and being that these instance variables are all in the Main class they cannot be non-static regardless but I wish to have there scope visible by the entire class.

Thank you for your feedback though and could you explain how the Pattern class is working in this situation with the Matcher class, I have never seen the two and its quite intriguing. I plan to read through its documentation as well so thank you for showing me!

Comment: If you are not on a server and have a standalone java programm, the static part might be ok...(Still feels strange to me but might be a personal issue ;-) To your other question: Since you obviously can't be sure what you'll find (e.g. (19), (19))  or maybe others?) I used a regex - the pattern and matcher represent the java regex mechanism. The regex takes everything in beetween two brackets (...). So it would also work for e.g. `(((((19)))))))` or `lsadfja(19))))` or other potential strings

Comment: Yeah, it is just a standalone java program, but thank you for the advice. I'm pursuing a computer science degree and every little bit of knowledge I can get from a more intellectual computer scientist or programmer means a lot!

Comment: Another possibility instead of the regex would be the String indexof(...) or contains() methods. This however requires that you know the number you expect in advance (which is not the case if I understand you correctly)